# Get current language in Portable Object Localization using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, multilingual

I have a ASP.NET CORE 3.1 c# Web Application with multilanguage support.
The multilanguage support uses Portable Object Localization.
I'm in need to get the current language via Javascript.
It is stored in a cookie setted using the following method :

```
    //GET /SetLanguage
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1), IsEssential= true }
        );
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Hoe can I do it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following code.

```
var current = document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((r, v) => {
                 const parts = v.split('=')
                 return parts[0] === '.AspNetCore.Culture'? decodeURIComponent(parts[1]) : r
                      }, '').split('|')[0].split('=')[1]
```